# How can I turn on mysql php function auto-completion?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have two related questions, being with how can I turn on mysql php functions auto-completion ? I mean If I type a function like this "phpin" the editor will pop-up `phpinfo();` but when I type "mysql/w i" It doesn't show up anything, that's the first one .

second question is what's the name and what editors does support this :

in some IDE's and very few editors like VSCode , when you type any built-in code for a certain language it will pop-up auto-complete with extended information like in PHP for example if I type "mysqli":

it shows something like this `mysqli(all string : $host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)`

so I got how to use that function , so I simply type mysqli() with the desired information , few of the some that support this support an additional feature do this if I type "mysqli($host,$user,$dbName)"

it show this `mysqli($host,$user,`**$password**`,$dbName,$port)`
which indicates that password is required for successful use .

So the **TL;DR** what editors does support Intel (if I'm right) and how can I turn such thing in Atom or VSCode ?

Comment: I think you might be better off with posting the question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TobiasF. Okay, Thank you.
I came here by a link refereed by official VSCode website .